# Built-in storage unit conversions utilty in Java?

Tags: java, units-of-measurement

there doesn't seem to be an existing util class for converting a storage unit from one to another in Java, am I right?  Or is there one actually I wasn't aware of?

What I was looking for is something like [java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) utility.  I can implement the equivalent for storage unit by myself, but just thought I would ask first before reinventing the wheel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [JSR-275](https://jsr-275.dev.java.net/). Depending on what you want to do, might be a bit of an overkill. Or you could take a look at [Commons Monitoring](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/monitoring/). They deal with some storage units I think, but again, the library itself is probably too much when want just the class.

Answer (score 2):

It may be overkill for what you need but JSR-275 is a Java API for units and conversions which includes DataAmount and DataRate.  There is a reference implementation available.

See https://jsr-275.dev.java.net/